# sys.path.append causing 500 error in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app that is giving me 500 when I import a file using sys.path.append('path/to/file.py)

Here is my file located in /var/www/html/ip.py which flask is calling:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/auto/conf/') 
from config import config  

server_username = config['server_username']
server_password = config['server_prod_password']

def check_ip(ip_addr):
    return "test"
```

Here is my /auto/conf/config.py:

```
import os
import ConfigParser

# Define names of dir and file
CRED_DIR = 'cred'
FILE_NAME = 'cred.conf'

# Path to cred file
my_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
cred_dir = os.path.join(my_dir, CRED_DIR)
file_path = os.path.join(cred_dir, FILE_NAME)

# Load the conf file with ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
config.read(file_path)


# Build a config dictionary
config = {
    'server_username': config.get('server', 'username'),
    'server_password': config.get('server', 'password'),
    }
```

and cred.conf is located in /auto/cred/cred.conf and contains server info.

Now, here is the issue.  If I run python ip.py, it runs fine.  I added print statement and it was fetching proper server username and password.  But when I run it via Flask, it gives me 500 error.

Here are some of the things I tried:

-- If I comment out "from config import config" from ip.py, Flask runs returns "test" meaning it worked. It will not get server un and pw but atleast it does not 500.

-- If I move cred.conf and config.py to same directory as ip.py and comment out "sys.path.append('/auto/conf/')" and uncomment "from config import config", Flask works.

Any ideas why its happening?  I am thinking Flask does not like sys.path.append.  Is there any alternative I can use so Flask works?

Edit:

I changed ip.py to this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/auto/conf/') 
import config
```

and removed all code in config.py and it is still gving me error.  If I comment out "import config", Flask works.  Definitely it does not like importing in this fashion..

Comment: Flask should give a proper traceback in the server console/logs, or in the browser itself if you enable debug mode. Please post that traceback, it will say exactly why this is not working.

Comment: I have "app.run(debug=True)" already enable but not sure where would I see traceback.  /var/log/apache2/error.log is empty.  I am using REST API and using browser dev tools.